# INSERT multiple values to one column

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `d41973sd**`.`Firma` (`id`, `name`, `regNr`, `email`, `mtel`, `location_id`, `address`, `indeks`, `web`, `logo`, `language_id`, `category_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'Stalker', '123456', 'stalker@gmail.com', '5535557', '1', 'Tuve 54/1', '12918', 'www.stalker.ee', 'stalker.jpg', ('1','3'), '2');
```

But i have error, because of this ('1','3').
How i can insert multiple values in one column???

```
    CREATE TABLE Languages (
language_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
language VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_firma PRIMARY KEY (language_id)
);
CREATE TABLE Firma (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
language_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT FK_language_id FOREIGN KEY (language_id)
   REFERENCES Languages (language_id),
)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: How do you wish to insert the data? As a comma-separated list, or as two rows with the other fields duplicated?

Comment: I would like ti insert it to column language_id like 1,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass it as a string, for example:

```
INSERT INTO `Firma` 
(`id`, `name`, `regNr`, `email`, `mtel`, `location_id`, `address`, `indeks`, 
 `web`, `logo`, `language_id`, `category_id`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, 'Stalker', '123456', 'stalker@gmail.com', '5535557', '1', 'Tuve 54/1', 
 '12918', 'www.stalker.ee', 'stalker.jpg', '1,3', '2');
```

Of course, this will assume that a language exists with the PK `1,3` in order for your foreign key restraint to work...

Storing comma-separated values in database fields isn't a good idea. It demonstrates poor design and will make working with the data later down the line extremely difficult. You should move `languages` to an external link table, otherwise you're going to have to duplicate **a lot** of data for companies that support more than one language.

Comment: BenM, i am sorry, can u help me, or give some links, how to make an external link table ? Because i don't understand it..

Comment: Basically just create another table with `firma_id` and `language_id`.

Comment: and just insert in this table, firma_id = '1' with language_id = '1' and firma_id = '1' with language_id = '3' ? i am correct?

Comment: Exactly that. You can then easily find all languages which a company supports, or all companies which support a specific language.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a nice evening!